# Can we implement a table with data from another table that has the same ID but not the sime size in SQL?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

i have table 1
(SERVICE) (ID_Service , ID_Vehicle )
and Table 2
(FACT) (ID_Veh , ID_Parts , Quantity )
i want to copy ID_Service to table FACT where ID_Vehicle=ID_Veh and affect to the rest Columns null  when it doesn't match

But the problem here that it inserts the ID_SERvice ROWS without matching it with the ID_Vehicle and affecting NULL to the other rows !
Is it because that they have two different sizes !!

i ve tried the inner join but it didn't work

that's what i get
[image]

Comment: It would help if you use SQL terms. What do you mean you want to "COPY  ID_Service to table FACT where ID_Vehicle=ID_Veh and AFFECT to the rest Columns null when it doesn't match"? Why ID_Veh is not the same size as ID_Service? Try to clarify you question more.

Comment: Am sorry , i have two types of data , one has 1 million lignes and the other 100.000 
i have to put the data in the same table  using the inner join , the 100.000 lignes exist in the big table  so when i use inner join that should be useful but it only inserts null rows

Comment: Inner join is used to get only matching data between tables according to your criteria. When you do the SELECT (no insert is performed and nulls are generated). Maybe the criteria you specify does not exclude nulls. I suggest you build a simple case and test with it first. First, run the select and ensure you get what you want then try the insert.